# make object using Some of my command at runtime in orchard in

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I have some Command that I ant executed some times by End User(Admin Interface) in Orchard,

I know what's Recipe and Orchard.exe!

 but I want to execute my Commands by Admin Interface!

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload a recipe to the admin UI anytime check here: [Orchard Recipes](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Making-a-Web-Site-Recipe) and [here](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/run-orchard-recipes-from-orchard-dashboard-in-orchard-cms-1.7)
There are modules that once enabled run recipes.

and look at the source, but here is some code

```
 Recipe recipe = _recipeHarvester.HarvestRecipes(module.Descriptor.Id).FirstOrDefault(x => !x.IsSetupRecipe && x.Name == name);

        if (recipe == null) {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        try {
            _recipeManager.Execute(recipe);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Logger.Error(e, "Error while executing recipe {0} in {1}", moduleId, name);
            Services.Notifier.Error(T("Recipes contains {0} unsupported module installation steps.", recipe.Name));
        }
```